# How to import Excel file to CCK nodes?

Tags: nodes, 6, importing-exporting

Is there a way to import a Excel file into CCK nodes?

- Each Excel file contains only a single sheet
- First row of there sheet is header
- Data are only strings, numbers, and decimal numbers
- It's a daily task which will be performed by a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to save your Excel file to CSV format to be able to import more easily. Two options:

- **[Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import)**: You can certainly import CSVs with this, and I've used it successfully for huge spreadsheets before -- it's powerful, helpful and quite easy.
- **[Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds)**: Much more complex to get going than Node Import, but Feeds can in theory do everything you want and *much* more. Can also update existing nodes.

Either of these will allow you to import CSV data (exported from your Excel document) to nodes and their CCK fields.

Answer (score 0):

I use iMacro as a general solution to fill a lot of forms.

It is an addon for firefox that allows one to record and play macros.

Here is a link that explains how to fill forms from csv files: http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling.

The advantage of this method is that the form filling will follow all the flow a normal user filled form would. Javascript formatting, for instance, will be applied to the user input.

The disadvantage is that it is a rather slow method. It takes some time to prepare the macro and it may take a lot of time to perform the operation if you have a very large set of data.